# Renderer couldn't be found in current assembly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> Assets\Scripts\BGlooper.cs(17,41): error CS1061: 'Renderer' does not contain a definition for 'material' and no accessible extension method 'material' accepting a first argument of type 'Renderer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It shows me this when i try to start the scene. Can someone help me pls?

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{" + nameof(GetDebugerDisplay) + "(),nq}")]
public class BGlooper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0.1f;

    private Material mat;
    private Vector2 offset = Vector2.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        mat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        offset = mat.GetTextureOffset("_Maintex");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        offset.x = offset.x + speed * Time.deltaTime;
        mat.SetTextureOffset("_Maintex", offset);
    }

    private static object GetDebugerDisplay()
    {
        return ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you make `material` be `Material` instead?

Comment: Please change the question title to a brief summary of your question.

Comment: Also, please post the actual code, not a screenshot of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is on line 31. From what I know you can't use **return ToString();**. You have to use an object like **return object.ToString();** because ToString() is a method that transform something into a string(text) so you probably need an object for that. I hope it help. And also on line 17 it seems that "material" is not recognized so maybe you named it differently on your project.